# python set: result order getting changed

Tags: python, set

here is my code sample,

here i am using set in my list..

1. if end of list value is `9`, set([list]) result became shuffled
2. if it is `6` returning as it is..

**My question is,**

1) why its getting shuffled? in which order/basis its getting shuffled?

2) how to print without shuffle?

```
>>> a = set([2,4,5,9])
>>> a
set([9, 2, 4, 5])
>>> a = set([2,4,5,6])
>>> a
set([2, 4, 5, 6])
>>>
```

Comment: By definition sets, unlike lists, are always unordered.

Comment: Sets are unordered collection, it'll always shuffle elements when you iterate it. Use lists instead.

Comment: i know those.. my question is , if its 9 its shuffled if its 6 it wasnt